# Register and Resolve Generic Objects

Tags: automapper, autofac

i have some problems with Register my Interfaces.
I have the following Interfaces:

```
public interface IMapper<Q, T> { /* Mapper Helper Methods */ }
public interface ISourceObject { /* Properties */ }
public interface ITargetObject { /* Properties */ }
```

The Implementations are:

```
public class GenericMapper<Q, T> : IMapper<Q,T> { /* Mapper Helper Methods */ }
public class SourceObject : ISourceObject { /* Properties */ }
public class TargetObject : ITargetObject { /* Properties */ }
```

In my Autofac Module i want to Register it as following:

```
builder.RegisterType<GenericMapper<SourceObject, TargetObject>>().As<IMapper<ISourceObject, ITargetObject>>();
```

And resolve it via:

```
Container.Resolve<IMapper<ISourceObject, ITargetObject>>();
```

The Automapper Profile Configuration is:

```
CreateMap<ISourceObject, ITargetObject>()
                    // ForMember Mappings
.ForAllMembers(o => o.Condition((src, dest, value) => value != null));
```

When i start my Unittest, it crashes with the following Stacktrace:

```
at Autofac.Builder.RegistrationBuilder.CreateRegistration(Guid id, RegistrationData data, IInstanceActivator activator, IEnumerable`1 services, IComponentRegistration target)
   at Autofac.Builder.RegistrationBuilder.CreateRegistration[TLimit,TActivatorData,TSingleRegistrationStyle](IRegistrationBuilder`3 builder)
   at Autofac.Builder.RegistrationBuilder.RegisterSingleComponent[TLimit,TActivatorData,TSingleRegistrationStyle](IComponentRegistry cr, IRegistrationBuilder`3 builder)
   at Autofac.RegistrationExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<RegisterType>b__0(IComponentRegistry cr)
   at Autofac.ContainerBuilder.Build(IComponentRegistry componentRegistry, Boolean excludeDefaultModules)
   at Autofac.ContainerBuilder.Build(ContainerBuildOptions options)

System.ArgumentException: 
    System.ArgumentException: The type 'App.Test.Models.GenericMapper`2[App.Test.Models.SourceObject,App.Test.Models.TargetObject]' is not assignable 
    to service 'App.Test.Models.IMapper`2[[App.Test.Models.ISourceObject, App.Test, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],
    [App.Test.Models.ITargetObject, App.Test, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'..
```

What do i wrong here?
When i Register the Implementations, the resolving works without a Problem. But it would be Hardwired to the implementations and that, i dont want. Can i resolve it that way or do i have to use the hard wired Version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is a problem with your interface definitions. If you pull Autofac entirely out of the mix and just test it manually, you can see the evidence:

```cs
[Fact]
public void TypesAreCompatible()
{
    var init = new GenericMapper<SourceObject, TargetObject>();
    var cast = (IMapper<ISourceObject, ITargetObject>)init;
    Assert.Same(init, cast);
}
```

This will fail on the line that starts with `var cast` and give the exception:

```
System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'GenericMapper`2[SourceObject,TargetObject]' to type 'IMapper`2[ISourceObject,ITargetObject]'.
```

The reason is that [your `IMapper` interface is not *covariant*.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/creating-variant-generic-interfaces) In simpler terms, that means you can't put a *more derived* type in as Q or T and have it "magically work." It has to be exact.

Update your interface to tell C# that it's OK to use covariant types by putting `out` in front of the type parameters.

```
public interface IMapper<out Q, out T> { }
```

Once you do that, the test I put above will work... and so will the Autofac registration.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It works like a charme and i learned a new thing about Generics. Thanks for the link btw. i read the article to understand it in the future.